# async/await, data fetching, and unresolved promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm running into an issue in an nodejs application I'm working on and can't seem to find a solution.

I'm working with the GitHub API to:

1. Fetch repositories from a given user
2. Fetch issues of every retrieved repository
3. Bringing the data together into one "repo" object

Step 3 is where problems arise.
I'm working with two async functions,`getReposForUser()` and `getIssuesForRepo()`, which behave as follows

```
async function getReposForUser(username) {
    // Fetch user repos from GitHub
    var result = await github.repos.getForUser({
        username: username,
        per_page: 100
    })
    // Grab issues for each repo
    repos = repos.map(repo => {
        return getIssuesForRepo(repo);
    });
    // console.log(repos);
 }


async function getIssuesForRepo(repo) {
/* 
    if there are issues available, fetch them and attach
    them to the repo object (under a property named issues).
    otherwise, assign the issues property a value of null
*/
if (repo.has_issues) {
    let issues = await github.issues.getForRepo({
        owner: repo.owner.login,
        repo: repo.name,
        state: 'open'
    });
    repo.issues = issues;
    return repo;
} else {
     return repo.issues = null;
    }
}
```

When I try to `console.log(repos)` after `getIssuesForRepo()` runs, I get an array of Promises. After doing some research, it's become clear that async/await functions return Promises. Ok, got that. My question is, **what can I do in order to create a new array of objects with the resolved value of those promises?** Basically, I want to attach the array of issues retrieved for each repo to its respective repo.

Thanks in advance to anyone who might help.

Also, why does this work inside `getReposForUser()` after `getIssuesForRepo()` runs?

```
let firsRepo = await getIssuesForRepo(repos[0]);
console.log(firsRepo);
```

In this case, I actually see the object, not the unresolved promise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what can I do in order to create a new array of objects with the resolved value of those promises?

`await` [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on the array of promises:

```
repos = await Promise.all(repos.map(repo => {
    return getIssuesForRepo(repo);
}));
```

---

Side note: Your `map` callback can just *be* `getIssuesForRepo`:

```
repos = await Promise.all(repos.map(getIssuesForRepo));
```

`map` calls its callback with the entry, its index, and the array being mapped. Since your `getIssuesforRepo` only uses its first argument, the extra two will be ignored.

Comment: `repos = await Promise.all(repos.map(getIssuesForRepo));` #codegolf ;)

Comment: @Matt: I don't get what happened there. The edit history says I added that, then you removed it without making any other changes, then you added it back. ??

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: that did it. thank you so much. brilliant and elegant answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't know, when I commented this, it said I edited the answer! Your current revision is wrong though, it doesn't pass anything to `getIssuesForRepo`

Comment: @Matt: yes, I picked up on that and changed it to `repos = await Promise.all(repos.map(repo => getIssuesForRepo(repo)))`. Other than that, no issues.

Comment: @JaySeeCode awesome! Yeah we are just debugging a website we've used for like a decade x_x

Comment: @JaySeeCode & Matt - The second version shouldn't have had `map =>` in it; fixed.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: 1. `this` isn't a "scope variable." 2. It'll be either `undefined` or a reference to the global object with **both** examples in the answer, not just the second.